# Proving a polynomial is not divisible

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, divisibility

Let $k\geq2$ be even and let $f(x)=x^{k}+x^{k-1}+...+1\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$

I want to prove that there is no linear polynomial that divides $f(x)$

So I figured that if there was $g(x)=x-\alpha$ that divides $f(x)$ I would should've get $f(\alpha)=0$, so I need to show that $f(\alpha)\neq0$...

Any hints? Plus, if someone can pinpoint the difference  between $\mathbb{R}[x]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ in this proof will be great!

Comment: Hint: rational root theorem: (That alone is a big difference between $\mathbb{R}[x]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[x]$! But note that if $k$ is odd, $f(x)$ MUST have at least one root in $\mathbb{R}[x]$.) But it looks to me like $x^{3}+x^{2}+x+1$ has $-1$ as a root, so I'm not sure your claim is true. Do you require that $k$ is even, by chance?

Comment: you're right. fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

With the caveat of AWertheim ($(x+1)$ divides $f(x)$ for $k$ odd), hint: what is and what roots in $\Bbb C$ has $(x-1)f(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f(x)$ is monic with integer coefficients, and hence, any root of $f(x)$ is an algebraic integer. Recall that if an algebraic integer is rational, then it is an integer. Hence, it suffices to show that $f(x)$ has no roots in $\mathbb{Z}$. Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}$. It is clear $\alpha \geq 0$ is not a root, so we consider $\alpha < 0$. To see that $f(-1) \neq 0$, reduce modulo $2$, and note that $$f(-1) = (-1)^{2k} + (-1)^{2k-1} + \cdots + 1 \equiv 1^{2k} + 1^{2k-1} + \cdots + 1 \equiv \underbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}_{2k+1\text{ times}} \equiv 1 \pmod 2$$

Consider $\alpha < -1$. Then $|\alpha| > 1$, so in particular, $|\alpha|^{n} < |\alpha|^{n+1}$ for any natural $n$. We see then that:

$$f(\alpha) = (\alpha^{2k}+\alpha^{2k-1})+(\alpha^{2k-2}+\alpha^{2k-3})+\cdots+(\alpha^{2}+\alpha)+1$$

But each term $(\alpha^{2i}+\alpha^{2i-1}) > 0$, so $f(\alpha) > 0$ for every integer $\alpha < -1$. Hence, $f(x)$ has no roots over the integers and hence no roots over the rationals.

Alternatively, you can again reduce $f(\alpha)$ modulo $2$; in either case, you can see $f(k) \equiv 1 \pmod 2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was much informative and educational, but we haven't covered the rational root theorm so I don't think I'm suppose to use it

Comment: Hmmm. Do you know Gauss' lemma ($f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ if and only if it is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$)?

Comment: Yes, we did cover Gauss' lemma

Comment: Ok, I'll try to write another answer using Gauss' lemma. :)

Comment: If k is an integer, you can show f(k) is always odd.